# Mission Control to App Exposé

Tags: macos, mission-control

In Snow Leopard you could switch to App Exposé from global Exposé by clicking an icon in the Dock. Doing the same in Lion merely exits you from Mission Control and focuses on that app.

Is there a way to go to a given App Exposé from Mission Control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you activate Mission Control whilst hovering the mouse over an app in the dock, it will do an Exposé for that app.

Activating Mission Control any other time will do a global Exposé as you say.

While in mission control, if you slide one finger up on the magic mouse (imagine it's a 2 two finger swipe with a trackpad) whilst hovering over the app windows, it'll Exposé the selected app's windows

In one of the earlier developer previews you could slide one finger up (on the magic mouse) over a dock icon while in Mission Control and it would trigger a per-app Exposé. Alas, it seems this feature has been removed.

There could be a hidden switch to turn it back on, but I've not had a play around with those 'secrets' apps to have a look yet.

Comment: After a few tries it appears the first one actually requires an App Exposé swipe over the icon, not a Mission Control one. A two finger double tap also works. It is indeed a scroll swipe (one finger with magic mouse, two on a trackpad) that focus and spreads the app windows a bit. None of those you or I mentioned allow to go from Mission Control to App Exposé. It's all the more sad to learn that Apple actually disabled it.

Comment: Is there any non-swipy way to focus on a selected app's windows within Mission Control? I don't have a Magic Mouse or trackpad.

Answer (score 2):

- Swipe up with 3 fingers = show mission control.
- When mission control is shown, move your mouse to the app window, and
- Swipe up with 2 fingers

This will show the app's windows.

Comment: This spreads the app windows but is not the same as App Exposé, which also shows minimized windows and recently opened documents (for apps that support it, e.g TextEdit or Pages).